# in this attentional blink experiment why is the second letter visible when the lag is low but not when the lag is high

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, brain, consciousness

[image]

this image is from the book [Consciousness and the Brain by Stanislas Dehaene](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0670025437)

the book describes the image as follows :

> The attentional blink illustrates the temporal limitations of
> conscious perception. When we view a stream of digits interspersed
> with an occasional letter, we easily identify the first letter (here
> an M) but not the second (here a T). While we are committing the first
> letter to memory, our consciousness temporarily “blinks,” and we fail
> to perceive a second stimulus presented within the next instant.
> NOTE: ms = milliseconds throughout.

why is T2 visible ≈75% of the time when the lag between the T1 and T2 is 100ms ?